# Writing a for loop or iteration in python to perform the same commands on a list of URLs?

Tags: python, html, string, for-loop, web-scraping

So I've written a chunk of code which retrieves a set of shortened HTML from the desired URL:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re


url = "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-1.html"

page = urlopen(url)

html_bytes = page.read()

html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")

start_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: Top Songs -->")

end_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: lyrics -->")

clean = html[start_index:end_index]

print(clean)
```

But there are 11 (basically identical) pages over which I need to run this same chunk. I've put them into a string:

```
allpages = ["https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-1.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-2.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-3.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-4.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-5.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-6.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-7.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-8.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-9.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-10.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-11.html"]
```

But I'm failing to derive a concise way to perform the original code on all of the URLs. I could, of course, write unique code for each individual page, but that would require 11x the amount of necessary code and defeat the purpose of my using python in the first place

Comment: `for url in allpages` will provide you with each url in your list, then just write the duplicated code in the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through your allpages list, which will iterate through each url stored and with each iteration, you can perform the flow of your previous code

```
# using your earlier code

for i in allpages:
   #where i becomes the url which you pass through
    page = urlopen(i) # i here represents each iteration and in this case each url
    html_bytes = page.read()

    html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")

    start_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: Top Songs -->")

    end_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: lyrics -->")

    clean = html[start_index:end_index]
    print(clean)
    ....
```

#Option2:
also you can wrap it in a function and use map it to return a list. with map you pass a function and an iterable(in this case your list of urls) and map does the iteration for you.

```
def url_func(x):
    page = urlopen(url)
    html_bytes = page.read()
    html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    start_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: Top Songs -->")
    end_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: lyrics -->")
    clean = html[start_index:end_index]
    return clean

final_result= list(map(url_func,allpages))
```

so in final_result, you have stored a list of all the clean html, each item would correspond with the expected result for your url.

Comment: absolute king. it's tough getting the basics down as a beginner, and that succinct explanation will go a long long way. much appreciated